# Magento 2 - How to open login & Sign up form in POPUP window

Tags: magento2, login, page-layouts

I required to display login / Signup in popup window.

Have created the login module as per this link 

Extension installed successfully but onclick of Login/signup button no action is performed.
Only the URl Gets changed http://localhost/domain/**#social-login-popup**

Comment: Thanks Ankit Shah, Mageplaza extension installed successfully but  i can’t get the popup working on login

Comment: Thanks Ankit Shah to suggest the plugin. Made some changes in popup.js and it started working

Comment: Good to hear @Sanj

Comment: Maybe this would help https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208608/46716