# Magento 2 login popup not working

Tags: magento2

Am working on Magento 2.3, I have issue with login popup is not showing. What i have done is "Disable Guest Checkout", I have noticed that element below is not rendered in the review basket page.

```
<div class="modals-wrapper">
```

I tried this solution to fix it: https://www.siphor.com/add-a-login-popup-in-magento-2/

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue its was my mistake,i had removed the popup block long time ago in default.xml, then i followed this question and working fine.

[Call default Magento 2 authentication popup from a custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208388/call-default-magento-2-authentication-popup-from-a-custom-module)