# how to show customer authentication popup when clicking on checkout button in minicart while guest checkout is enable mangento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, popup, authentication

I want to check if a user is logged in before proceeding to checkout. On the basis of customer login condition, i want to show the login popup if not login, and redirect to checkout if logged in already.

**IMPORTANT: I have guest checkout enabled in the configuration. Because I want user to checkout with guest account**

I am able to redirect user to login page when not logged in. But not able to use popup instead of redirecting it to login page.

to redirect user to login page, I did the following changes in my minicart.js file:

```
var cc = customerData.get('customer');
if(cc().firstname){
    console.log("customerData",true);
    var urls = window.checkout.checkoutUrl; 
}else{
    console.log("customerData",false);
    $( document.body ).removeClass( "logedin" );
    var urls = window.checkout.customerLoginUrl;
}
```

please help me find out how to use popup login instead redirecting to login page.

Comment: The answer provided here should fit with your requirement.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/364594/6572

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, try to implement your code as per the reference site.

[Call default Magento 2 authentication popup from a custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208388/call-default-magento-2-authentication-popup-from-a-custom-module)

Comment: Hi, @nits thanks for commenting. but I already tried this solution its does open the popup..but not on the first click...It requires a complete page reload to respond on click.

Comment: @Nit, first of all, every popup requires to load the page and this popup is completely dependent on the section to be loaded, then after it will open the popup. Or there is another solution like load login field in the HTML and hide/show this HTML in the popup. This will work for you.

Comment: @Nit Please try this extension. https://github.com/manishjoy/customer-ajax-login
Hope this will help.

Comment: I will try both of your suggestion and let you know if I successful. please stay connected

Comment: Sure, you can email me if you need my help. nitish250788@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js` file in your theme and remove `cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false` from `if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {}` condition. So if customer is not logged in then it will open popup.

**Original Code:**

```
if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
    ...
}
```

**After condition removal:**

```
if (!customer().firstname) {
    ...
}
```

As per old condition, it checks if a customer is not logged and guest checkout is disabled and as per new condition it will check only if a customer is not logged in.

Comment: tried it already buddy..not working

Comment: did you checked that the sidebar.js file change was reflected in static content.?

Comment: yes..i removed cache and even browser cache..but no luck.

Comment: run setup upgrade and content deploy commands and then check.